# Dynamically determining proper file system path in Heroku or in local dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails app that has some scripts that ingest data, and these scripts are run with rails runner.  The data files I need to read are in my Rails codebase e.g. in resources/data.  I need to be able to run these scripts in local dev or in heroku, but I'm having difficulty coming up with a clean and permanent way to figure out in the code what the path to these data files is in each environment.  Referring to RAILS_ROOT in Heroku didn't work for me, and I thought that was going to be the best approach.  (I know that in Heroku the path is /app/resources... but that doesn't really help solve the problem.)

What's the best way to do this?  I've seen one approach that looked for tell-tale strings in ENV but that's a hack.

Thanks

Comment: RAILS_ROOT is dead. Try `Rails.root` instead, that should be portable.

Comment: thanks, that works!